# .htaccess mod-rewrite URL with language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect URL like this:

```
myweb.com/en/page
```

to

```
myweb.com/info-page.php?str=page&lang=en
```

and URL like this:

```
myweb.com/de/page
```

to

```
myweb.com/info-page.php?str=page&lang=de
```

This code does not work (error 404):

```
RewriteRule ^/?(en|de)/page/ info-page.php?str=$2&lang=$1
```

Where am I wrong?
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(en|de)/(contact|aboutus|etc)/? info-page.php?str=$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

$1 is for the first `(...)`, and $2 for the second.

Comment: I forgot to emphasise that I need this rule only for 5 pages (for example contact, about us etc.). So I need to specify the page in the rule.